# <div> triangle won't change color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a div triangle and it is placed perfectly. When I put it in I wanted it to be a different color than grey. So I went back to my class (css) and put `background: red` and it changed the area around it red not the triangle itself. If  you can help it would be appreciated!

```css
.triangle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left: 1030px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1030px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 500px solid #555;
  position: absolute;
  left: -322px;
  top: 160px;
  z-index: -1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triangle is made out of a border, so the only way to change the color is to change the border color. The snippet below works.

```css
.triangle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 0px;
  border-left: 1030px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1030px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 500px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  left: -322px;
  top: 160px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, i didn't even see the color tag there. Sorry i am a noob

Answer (score 0):

Change the `border-bottom` instead

```
border-bottom: 500px solid red;
```